# creating a JAVA jnlp file

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

Hi this is my xml file to create a JNLP all I get is a Navigation to webpage cancelled even though I am specifying that my jar is already located in my c:\Users directory

```
<!--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!-- JNLP File for TableDemo --> 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" 
   codebase="c:/Users/" 
  href="TableDemo.jnlp"> 
<information> 
<title>TableDemo</title> 
<description>Java Table Demo </description> 
<offline-allowed/> 
</information> 
<resources> <jar href="TableDemo.jar" /> 
<j2se version="1.6+"> 
</resources> <application-desc main-class="TableDemo" /> 
</jnlp> 

-->
```

Why can I not produce a TableDemo.jnlp file?

Comment: dogbane - thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your codebase to:

```
codebase="file:///c:/Users"
```

as it must be a URL.

Comment: hi dogbane - no not worked. Can I use my local host Joomla site ie <!-- "http://localhost/Joomla/MyJava/" --> tried it still not working

Comment: I have tried using my site's URL:- "http://www.derivativessoftware.com/MyJoomla/MyJava/"  and have the jar file in the MyJava dir still same message

Comment: @Kurt How are you running it? Are you using java6? See if it works from the command line: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaws.exe C:\users\TableDemo.jnlp`

Comment: sorry new to java how can I create this from command line? I have just copied the code and saved it into the .xml file above then I double click it within windows vista - yes I have Java6

Comment: @Kurt When you double-click the jnlp file what application does it open with?

Comment: thanks for your replys. dogbane that's my problem I cannot produce the JNLP file in the first place the .xml code is to produce the jnlp file which it does not do, how can i get the .xml above to work to produce the jnlp?